# g++ fails to link libraries while creating a shared object

Tags: c++, static-linking, linker-errors

I am trying to create a static library for my engine.
The command (in a makefile) is:

```
g++ -c -fPIC window.cc -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2 -std=c++14 -I../include/ && g++ -static window.o -lSDL2 -lGL -lGLEW -o ../distribute/so/window.so
```

So, the first command compiles successful, but the other one outputs this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I definitely need those arguments. Can we fix it?

Comment: Where are the library files located?

Comment: Standard location of Ubuntu, I installed them via apt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the exact paths of the library files to be linked with.
The directories that contain them should be added to your link line with `-L`.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesnt work for me, also, wouldn`t it be OS dependent then?

Comment: When I link with -L /usr/lib/libGL.so -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so, the shared objects are found, but I keep getting errors about g++ not finding the library functions

Comment: You're statically linking it though so it won't use `.so`. It will use `.a` libraries.
You need to show the exact error if you want people to help you debug things.

Comment: And you put directories after `-L`, not the file

Comment: you probably need to install the '-dev' version of those packages to get the static libs

Comment: Ok, sorry, it finaly worked. That -static wasn`t supposed to be there, I guess -_- Anyway, thanks for answering!